# Python dataframe Renaming two columns into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The dataframe below has two names for one. The dataframe is of type "column.pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex"
This is what list for the data frame looks like

```
[('caption', ''),
('', ''),
('tackles', 'TOT'),
('tackles', 'SOLO'),
('tackles', 'SACKS'),
('tackles', 'TFL'),
('misc', 'PD'),
('misc', 'QB HTS'),
('misc', 'TD'),
('misc', 'Unnamed: 8_level_1'),
('gameid', '')]
```

Maybe also displaying what the info displays may help. In the event that the list function maybe is not clear.

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 24 entries, 0 to 23
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column                      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                      --------------  -----  
 0   (caption, )                 24 non-null     object 
 1   (, )                        24 non-null     object 
 2   (tackles, TOT)              24 non-null     int64  
 3   (tackles, SOLO)             24 non-null     int64  
 4   (tackles, SACKS)            24 non-null     int64  
 5   (tackles, TFL)              24 non-null     int64  
 6   (misc, PD)                  24 non-null     int64  
 7   (misc, QB HTS)              24 non-null     int64  
 8   (misc, TD)                  24 non-null     int64  
 9   (misc, Unnamed: 8_level_1)  0 non-null      float64
 10  (gameid, )                  24 non-null     object 
dtypes: float64(1), int64(7), object(3)
memory usage: 2.2+ KB
```

How would I change that to 1 name per column with no spaces

```
['caption_',
'_', 
'tackles_TOT',
'tackles_SOLO',
'tackles_SACKS',
'tackles_TFL',
'misc_PD',
'misc_QBHTS',
'misc_TD',
'misc_Unnamed:8_level_1',
'gameid_']
```

Comment: What is the type of your column index: `type(df.columns)`? MultiIndex or Index?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. the type command yields this: "pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index().map('_'.join)
print(df.columns)

# Output
Index(['caption_', '_', 'tackles_TOT', 'tackles_SOLO', 'tackles_SACKS',
       'tackles_TFL', 'misc_PD', 'misc_QB HTS', 'misc_TD',
       'misc_Unnamed: 8_level_1', 'gameid_'],
      dtype='object')
```

If your column index is already an `Index` and not a `MultiIndex`, you can remove `to_flat_index()` but the result is the same even if it's an `Index`.

Comment: the code errored out error: "TypeError: can only join an iterable"

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I used `df.index` instead of `df.columns`... Can you check it please?

Comment: Corralien thanks for fast reply I am still getting an error. This is the error: "name 'Index' is not defined"

Comment: Can you update your post with the full Traceback when you use `df.columns.to_flat_index().map('_'.join)` please

Comment: Your last statment did not error. But the dataframe remained unchanged. The column type remains the same "pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex". I also tried assigning it do df1 and the result was Index(['caption_', '_', 'tackles_TOT', 'tackles_SOLO', 'tackles_SACKS',
       'tackles_TFL', 'misc_PD', 'misc_QB HTS', 'misc_TD',
       'misc_Unnamed: 8_level_1', 'gameid_'],
      dtype='object')

Comment: Simply `df.columns = df.columns.to_flat_index().map('_'.join)` to set the columns

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it?